# Ready Chat Sdk for flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to have a ready chat for my flutter app, without coding anything so is there an sdk I can implement right away? I tried SendBird's ready sdk but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout getstream flutter SDK - https://getstream.io/chat/sdk/flutter/.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [QuickBlox Flutter Chat SDK](https://quickblox.com/sdk/flutter-chat-sdk/) to implement chat functionality into your application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).